# VBA - comma/dot number format (US > EU (German))

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Got a piece of code where are some parameters that I want to have with (,) instead of (.) What my code is doing, taking some system specific files (.dif) and convert them into .txt , but there I managed to convert 
 `Column A` to certain date format (instead of US format), but problem is with another Columns. `Column M` to `Column T` are "Temperatures", and US format is with (.), so you have for instance 25.5 C or German (EU) is with (,) 25,5 C.

p.s. Temperatures are marked with T11, T21, T31 and so on...

What I wanted is to convert them all to Comma and I am not managing with `.NumberFormat` or changing it in Excel > Advanced > 1000 separator options.

I am getting .txt file but with still (.) and that makes me always unnecessary trouble when importing it to Power Query /BI > have to always remove previous step (not a lot of people is familiar with PBI and Editor, and when you say to someone to take care of it...people forgetting easily because you have lot of steps to do..)

This is part of the code:

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder, targetFolder As String)
Dim Workbook
Dim SubFolder

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder, targetFolder
Next
Dim File
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For Each File In Folder.Files

    ' *** Operate on each file ***
    Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File)

    ' *** Sort, filter and rename each file/column ***
    If Workbook.FileFormat = -4158 Then
        Set Workbook = Workbook.ActiveSheet
            'Workbook.Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Delete
            'Workbook.Columns("E").EntireColumn.Delete
            'Workbook.Columns("R:T").EntireColumn.Delete
            Workbook.Rows("1").Delete

            Range("A1:W1").Value = Array("Date/Time", "P0 [mbar]", "P1 [mbar]", "P3 [mbar]", "P7 [mbar]", "PS160 [mbar]", "P190 [mbar]", "P220 [mbar]", _
            "Q1 [ppb]", "Q2 [ppb]", "Q3 [ppb]", "Q4 [ppb]", _
            "T11 [°C]", "T21 [°C]", "T31 [°C]", "T12 [°C]", "T22 [°C]", "T32 [°C]", "T01 [°C]", "T02 [°C]", "FM1 [slm]", "FM2 [slm]", "FM3 [slm]")

            Workbook.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"
            'Workbook.Columns("M").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("N").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("O").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("P").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("Q").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("R").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("S").NumberFormat = "#.###"
            'Workbook.Columns("T").NumberFormat = "#.###"


    ' *** Preparing new folder for filtered/sorted files ***
        Dim FLDR_NAME As String
        FLDR_NAME = Mid(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\") + 1)
        Dim fso As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        FLDR_NAME = targetFolder & "\" & FLDR_NAME
        If Not fso.FolderExists(targetFolder) Then
               fso.CreateFolder (targetFolder)
        End If

        If Not fso.FolderExists(FLDR_NAME) Then
               fso.CreateFolder (FLDR_NAME)
        End If

    ' *** Save As Converter_Converted as separate file ***
        Dim newFileName As String
        newFileName = FLDR_NAME & "\" & Workbook.Name & ".txt"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbook.SaveAs FileName:=newFileName

    ' *** Close and SaveAs ***
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

[image: After converting with VBA]

[image: PowerBI (Editor)]

This in PBI Editor is auto- change type, what I dont wanna everytime to have.

[image: As it should be!]

On last picture from PBI, is actually what I wanted, but without further steps of replacing values and changing values.

Comment: If your `.txt` file has numbers with the comma for the decimal indicator, why can't you create a Query that includes that parameter?  Then your users would just need to **Update** the query; perhaps pointing it to a different file.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No it doesnt, they are (dots) after conversion.. then in PQ I always have to delete that step of auto- changing...

Comment: Something I'm not understanding.  If I set up a query to import a file, where the decimals are commas, once I've done that, it will always interpret the commas as decimals.  What are you doing in your Query?

Comment: Perhaps if you shared some text representing the `.txt` file along with a screenshot of how you want to display it in Excel, as well as the relevant Windows Regional Settings, a solution could be suggested.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No it wont. As I say, the data that I am having are a bit specific (even after conversion). WHen I change my regional settings to US then I am just "plug and play" the data, without any changes... but with EU settings, Power Query makes one Additional step where automatically changes the Data type into something I dont want to. I assume you know that already. 
I am dealing with different data, US into EU...

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You got a pics...uploaded!

Comment: The information you've supplied does not correlate with your question.  I thought you wanted to interpret US 27.4 --> EU 27,4.  But your screenshot (I asked for one showing what you wanted for a result) shows, apparently, 27.4 -- 274.  Which do you want?

Comment: **IF** your WRS is using comma for the decimal separator, and **IF** you want to convert the US-centric decimal numbers to your system, then you should be using the `Change Type using Locale`, and specify `English(United States)` as the locale.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I just gave you an input what I am getting everytime (that whole number 274 for all the temperatures),...see on new picture, I have to manually change and replace type of the data. I could spare couple of steps if that can be made in VBA lines so I can have output file that I directly plug into Editor without bothering to change type....you got it??

Comment: There's no need.  Just `change data type using locale` in PQ to `en-US`, as I wrote.  Then re-use the query.  Sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ohh man, that was simple and useful suggest...it actually works!! :D   merci!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out finally something (for me at least is hell of a help)!

I way playing in PowerQuery Editor, and also with those formats, regional settings and so on... the quickest and easiest way to have your data "set" in adquate format (worked in my case - living in Germany), is once when you uploaded your data into editor, just go in Options > Regional settings > and Locale into English (UK) and hit REFRESH into the Editor - this one works flawlessly in my case, cant figure out 100% why Germany as locale doesnt work properly, but putting another Locale with one click is better than "remove steps" and format everyhting.

What I wanna say, it recognizes your data as long as your data set is homogenous and without any discrepancies...and again, it is not needed to change completely your regional settings on PC, just upload the data and during that you can alaways change into Editor everything you need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IF your Windows Regional System setting is using comma for the decimal separator, and IF you want to convert the US-centric decimal numbers to your system, then you should be using the **Change Type *using Locale***, and specify **English(United States)** `en-US` as the locale.

Comment: I encountered a "problem" actually by Date/Time format...once you changed to for instance US, then you will get proper "separator" but something else can turn into wrong format like in my case. But, as you have written it is everything connected to your Settings, Locale and Regional settings! No matter what and how did you change your Macro/VBA program, it will always take what is on your System in that moment! But it is interesting thing to know, especially for new users and anyone who might have similar issue! 

Thx Ron!