# Excel (VBA) does not keep my number format

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the following macro to import data from another Excel file that I get from SAP software.
But when the code runs it turns numeric values into text and I loose track of certain quantities caused by a clipboard limitation. It stores as text and converts dot into comma, and comma into dot
i.e: 100.000 (one hundred thousand) turns into 100,000 (one hundred)

I've tried to format the numeric values to keep the actual format,
macro that moves a tab to a new instead of coping it
find and replace comma into dot, and none of these have worked.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub SupplyData()

Dim SrcName As String 'Source workbook name
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook '
Dim DestWbk As Workbook

'Set the current workbook as the workbook to paste data

Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

'Search on computer for the workbook to copy data from

SrcName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
If SrcName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(SrcName)

'The local to paste the copied data

SrcWbk.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:M349").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:L")

SrcWbk.Close False

Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=""
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=""

End Sub
```

Comment: In the USA, one thousand and 50 cents is represented `1,000.50`, but in Spain it's `1.000,50`. Your input Excel file is in Spanish format, but your Excel application is in USA format. You are mislead in thinking that Excel interprets correctly the format of your input Excel file, this file probably doesn't store the numbers in an international way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA - comma/dot number format (US > EU (German))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582622/vba-comma-dot-number-format-us-eu-german)

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi
I've checked the region format before sending my problem, both excel file and excel application are in the same region.
What happens is the following:
with the declaration `Dim SrcName As String` when it opens the file in `SrcName = Application.GetOpenFilename...` all its content is converted to string, including numeric values. I would like to find a way that when the file opens, numeric values stay that way

Comment: Does "same region" mean like USA or Spain? Could you tell us what format is the source file, by opening it with notepad, is it like mojibake starting with the characters PK, or is it some plain text (probably CSV or tab-delimited format)?

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi, "same region" means Brazil.
From the beginning, I've created a macro to extract files from SAP software by saving it as a excel file (.xls) in the SAP software folder.
When I open the file the columns for material description is formatted as General and the comuns for quantities is formatted as Numeric, and when code to import the files runs all my data is converted to string/text data.

Answer (score 0):

Your destination workbook is set to use comma as a thousands separator while your copying workbook is set for period as a thousands separator.

While copying, VBA has the string value "100.000" that it took from the copying workbook. Then it puts the string value into the destination workbook. The destination workbook sees a number formatted as a string and automatically corrects it to a number using its number format settings. String value "100.000" is changed into Number 100.000 (One Hundred).

To fix this, ensure the values stored in the copying workbook are not strings so VBA will grab them as numbers. Or make sure both workbooks are using the same thousands separator symbol.

Comment: Hello,
I've tried to change the the separators and it still doesn't work :/